# How do I create pattern of kmer in unix for a given string?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have a string called `mystring=AACTCGCTTT`. I want to create a pattern of this string allowing 4 mismatches or kmer= 6 starting from the first letter and ending to the last last letter. I want this so I can grep these patterns in a text file. How do I do that in bash? So my pattern would look like this:

```
????CGCTTT
A????GCTTT
AA?T???TTT
```

Comment: Did you mean `????CGCTTT`? I don't know where you use that pattern, but usually `****` is the same as `*` and can match more than one or even zero letters.

Comment: Are the mismatches always consecutive? I.e., is `A*C*C*C*TT` invalid?

Comment: @Aaron No they are not always consecutive actually.

Comment: Then hek2mgl's answer should work nicely for you :)

Comment: @Aaron How would you do it if they are always consecutive?

Comment: I'd use an alternation of the 7 patterns `....CGCTTT` ... `AACTCG....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called [`agrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep) for that purpose:

```
agrep -4 AACTCGCTTT filename
```

From the man page:

> Searches for approximate matches of PATTERN in each FILE or standard input. Example: 'agrep -2 optimize foo.txt' outputs all lines in file 'foo.txt' that match "optimize" within two errors. E.g. lines which contain "optimise", "optmise", and "opitmize" all match.

Comment: There is this error: `agrep: the maximum number of errors is 8`. What is it about? My command is like this `agrep -20 TAAAATTTCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCGCTTT merged.fastq`

Comment: The maximum number which you can specify is `agrep -8`